# Is it theoretically beneficial to implement a linked list which remembers the node previously accessed?

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

I intended to implement a linked list that remembers the node previously accessed but not sure whether it is theoretically more beneficial to do so.

For example, if the user first calls an api which retrieves the 300th element and then makes another call which retrieves the 310th element. A normal linked list would do two potentially expensive linear lookup starts from the head or from the tail of the list. But if an implementation somehow remembers the 300th node during the first call and begins the second lookup from it, the second call would be much cheaper.

I failed to find related information about this topic, could anyone advise my thought is correct or wrong?

Comment: You can append in *O(1)* instead of *O(n)*, so yes. Most linked lists store both a reference to the first and last node.

Comment: Note that a linked list however is usually *not* used for indexed lookups. Retrieving the *k*-th element is normally not a good idea with a linked list.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a Linked-List in the first place? Why are other data-structures inappropriate?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It is the same for insertion/deletion, before insertion or deletion the list must first find the node in question, so retrieving an element is frequent and inevitable and I think caching the previous node accessed maybe beneficial.

Comment: @Dai I want to use a linked-list to speed up insertion/deletion in the middle of a list which is quite frequent in my program.

Comment: @Chris: but if you append to the end of the list (often the case), we know that the `last` node is that node, so the "scan" to the last node, is not necessary anymore.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry my wording is misleading, I don't mean the end of the list but the node accessed during the previous call to its api, like the 300th node in my example. Appending to the end of the list is not a problem however I inserts in the middle of the list a lot in my program.

Comment: "I want to use a linked-list to speed up insertion/deletion in the middle of a list which is quite frequent in my program" - but you said your program doesn't have a direct object reference (i.e. a pointer) and needs to do a linear-scan to find a node first - in which case you should use a Priority Queue Heap Tree instead of a Linked List - as both lookup and add/remove operations will be on the order of `O( log( n ) )`, while you can still dereference the head and tail in `O(1)` time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point in using a linked list for lookups, as there are better alternatives: priority queue, binary search tree, hash table, ...

But to answer the question:

If you keep a reference to the last accessed node in the list, and first start searching from that node, there is a possibility that you will not find the target node in that first scan, and still have to do a second scan, starting this time from the head of the list (making sure not to go beyond the node from where you started the first scan).

If the node being searched for has an equal probability to be at any index in the list, then there is no gain.

To see this clearly, imagine for a moment that the list is circular, where the tail is linked to the head. This actually represents what I described above: that a failing first scan must continue from the head. As assumed, all nodes in this circular list have an equal probability to be the node being searched for, and so there really is no preferential node: all nodes have an equal role in the "circle". It can easily be seen that any node would serve just as well as starting point for the search as any other.

It is only when you have more information, and there is a higher probability that the node being searched for is closer to the end of the list than the beginning, that you may find benefit in starting the search from any node you may still have access to.